# Why in "openssl pkeyutl -verify" is needed both public and private keys? Why isn't public key enough?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, rsa

I created a signature with:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey rsa.key.bob -in  plain -out plain.sig.bob
```

and to verify, Alice just needs to use Bob public key to check the authenticity of the message.

So why I have to use this (which require the private key):

```
openssl pkeyutl -verify -in plain -inkey rsa.key.bob -sigfile plain.sig.bob
```

and there is no option to just use the public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... and there is no option to just use the public key?

This option exists. [As documented](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html) you have to use the `-pubin` argument to specify that the key given with `-inkey` is a public key. You create the public key from the private key file for example with

```
openssl pkey -in rsa.key.bob -pubout -out rsa.pubkey.bob
```

With this you can do

```
openssl pkeyutl -verify -in plain -inkey rsa.pubkey.bob -pubin -sigfile plain.sig.bob
```

Comment: thanks it works. but now my question is: why do I have to specify the plaintext with -in ? Can't I just decrypt without specifying it? In a real case scenario the recipient does not have the plaintext.

Comment: @Allexj: You are doing __signatures__ here, not encryption. And verifying a signature is about checking that this signature is actually valid for the given content. *"In a real case scenario the recipient does not have the plaintext."* - and what is the client expected to verify then? That the peer has signed "something" w/o making clear what was actually signed?

Comment: so digital signatures are ALWAYS performed this way? knowing the plaintext? There is not case where you just decrypt using sender's public key and then see if message is readble without having the plaintext?

Comment: @Allexj: A digital signature is done by first hashing the original data and then applying the signature algorithm (which is essentially encrypting with the private key in case of RSA - but different with other signature algorithms). For one, that signature verification works by decrypting is specific to RSA signatures. And even this decryption does not return the original data but only the hash. So yes, a signature is expected to accompany the signed data, not include it. This is like in the analog world where the signature is part of a signed readable document and not standalone.